# How to do a groupby and correlation along rows in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a pandas df as shown below where there can be multiple group with names and variables x1, x2, x3 etc.

```
group name    x1        x2        x3
1      A      32        21        34
1      B      12        13        14
1      C      12        14        16
2      A      23        19        26
2      B      18        28        45
2      C      12        46        13
```

I would like to form a correlation matrix between each names for each individual group as shown below:

```
group 1
       A                           B                                              C
A      1        correlation between A and B in Group 1        correlation between A and C in Group 1
B      ``                          1                                              ``
C      ``                         ``                                              1

group 2
       A                           B                                              C
A      1        correlation between A and B in Group 2        correlation between A and C in Group 2
B      ``                          1                                              ``
C      ``                         ``                                              1
```

May I ask what functions in pandas will enable me to obtain such correlation matrix? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My approach with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
corr_df = (df.melt(['group','name'])
             .pivot_table(index = ['group','variable'],
                          columns = 'name',
                          values = 'value')
             .groupby('group')
             .corr()
            #.apply(pd.DataFrame.corr) #if previous line doesn't work
          )
print(corr_df)
name               A         B         C
group name                              
1     A     1.000000  0.142857  0.142857
      B     0.142857  1.000000  1.000000
      C     0.142857  1.000000  1.000000
2     A     1.000000  0.556267 -0.892854
      B     0.556267  1.000000 -0.122427
      C    -0.892854 -0.122427  1.000000
```

**Detail**

```
print(df.melt(['group','name'])
        .pivot_table(index = ['group','variable'],
                      columns = 'name',
                      values = 'value'))
name             A   B   C
group variable            
1     x1        32  12  12
      x2        21  13  14
      x3        34  14  16
2     x1        23  18  12
      x2        19  28  46
      x3        26  45  13
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to reshape the DataFrame so that the correlation is along columns allowing you to `groupby` and apply `pd.DataFrame.corr` directly.

```
(df.set_index(['group', 'name'])
   .stack().unstack('name')
   .groupby('group')
   .apply(pd.DataFrame.corr)
)
```

---

```
name               A         B         C
group name                              
1     A     1.000000  0.142857  0.142857
      B     0.142857  1.000000  1.000000
      C     0.142857  1.000000  1.000000
2     A     1.000000  0.556267 -0.892854
      B     0.556267  1.000000 -0.122427
      C    -0.892854 -0.122427  1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I got this error NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time